# What is the proper way to fix navigation?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

First of all i'm fixing an app thats similar to LogoQuiz -

The main menu depicts 3 buttons - Play, Options and about.

When a user taps "Play" they are taken to a new View controller to pick the levels -

Lets say they tap level one - the game opens a level one screen and the option to swipe between 2 screens of level one!

What would be the proper way to make the app in level 1 -

should i use "page control" so the user can navigate to the second part of level 1 -

My problem is I'm not able to find a solution that adds 2 view controllers which function with a page control - please shine some light on my issue if possible.

Can it be done with UI page control and how?

Comment: Im not so sure you need two whole VCs but regardless you could mimic this easily with custom transitions

Answer (score 0):

I found an old tutorial that might help:

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/